# Parse JS SDK: Bundle Size

Tags: parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I'm tasked with making a js application which uses parse more efficient. It currently uses webpack v4 and the parse js sdk.

I noticed that the largest module in my bundle is the parse sdk at a whopping 147KB after minification.

Here are examples depicting my entire use of this SDK. From what I can tell, there aren't that many network requests in the browser. Is there any way to get a smaller bundle size with this SDK or should I write the logic myself if bundle size is important?

("" is used instead of specific keys/config values, etc)

Initialization

```
Parse.initialize("");
Parse.serverURL = "";
```

Checking if logged in

```
if(Parse.User.current()) { ... do stuff }
```

Getting user info

```
const query = new Parse.Query("");
query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
return query.find();
```

Saving user info

```
const objectToSave = new Parse.Object("");
objectToSave("prop","value");
return objectToSave.save();
```

Logging in

```
return Parse.User.logInWith(authProvider, { authData: { id: userId, access_token: accessToken } }).then(...
```

Logging out

```
Parse.User.logOut()
```

Comment: Related, does anyone know if the parse js sdk does anything really complicated behind the scenes or does it really just make api calls and store some state for the session (because if it's simple, I'm more likely to roll my own client code)?

Answer (score 2):

If the 147KB is a big issue for you, you can write your own API calls using lower level Node.js libraries directly to the REST API: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/